# Loading cfg file into python - Wrong URL?

Tags: python, file, load

This is my what I have:

```
    myGrammar = nltk.data.load('file:C:\Users\Jay\Documents\buffalo.cfg')
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
  `Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Jay\Documents\Assignment9.py", line 8, in <module>
   myGrammar = nltk.data.load( 'file:C:\Users\Jay\Documents\buffalo.cfg')
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 610, in load
   resource_val = nltk.grammar.parse_cfg(_open(resource_url).read())
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 689, in _open
   return open(path, 'rb')
  IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\Jay\\Documents\x08uffalo.cfg'`
```

Does anyone know what my URL should be? Why do I get x08 instead of b in the error?

Answer (score 2):

Using a raw string as shown in RichieHindle's answer is one way to correct the character errors. Another is to escape the backslashes:

```
myGrammar = nltk.data.load('file:C:\\Users\\Jay\\Documents\\buffalo.cfg')
```

Another is to use forward slashes instead of backslashes (does work in Windows):

```
myGrammar = nltk.data.load('file:C:/Users/Jay/Documents/buffalo.cfg')
```

If you're still getting the same error after correcting this issue, then it would seem to indicate that there's something up with the file location you're specifying.. are you sure the location is correct?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've double checked everything, and it still won't let me load it for some reason. I'll try moving the file to a new directory.

Comment: Strange, please report back after you try this as I'm interested in what the problem is

Comment: Still no luck. I asked someone else, who said I need to use the 'parse_cfg' method instead of data.load(). That doesn't work either however, so I'm not quite sure what the issue is. Thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 0):

Use a raw string - note the leading `r` - for a string with embedded backslashes:

```
load(r'file:C:\Users\Jay\Documents\buffalo.cfg')
     ^
```

Otherwise some of your backslashes (eg. in `\b`) will turn normal characters into control characters.

Comment: Thanks for your help! That makes sense. Still isn't working for some reason though, same error.

Comment: no, it's showing up as a b now, which is great! It just has the same invalid mode or filename problem.

Comment: Sorry... assuming the file exists and is readable with sensible contents, I don't know what would cause that.